# MUI: useResizeContainer - The parent DOM element...has an empty height

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, mui-x-data-grid

I need help figuring this out. I know I'm getting this error because the parent element doesn't have a set height/width. And I also know that it is because the div is being hidden rather than not being rendered that this is happening.

The reason we are choosing to hide the grid when not in the "grid" view is that if the grid gets unmounted and then remounted we end up losing the selection state, filters, and search when we fully rerender.

Is there a way to get rid of this error? I'm kind of stuck on what else to try so any help/info would be appreciated. I've already tried adding a height&width to the parent div that is getting hidden and that didn't get rid of the error. I also tried adding the HxW into the theme in ThemeProvider.

here is just a basic structure of my code:

```
<div hidden={currentView === "grid" ? "" : "hidden"}>
     <randomNonImportantElement></randomNonImportantElement>
     <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <DataGridPremium {...props} ></DataGridPremium>
     </ThemeProvider>
</div>
```

I also tried adding the autoHeight prop to the DataGrid and that didn't work either.
I also didn't add all the props that I have to the datagrid to save my fingers.